# What other options are there in IClientProxy.SendAsync string method parameter?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm studying [azure signal R management sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/blob/dev/docs/management-sdk-guide.md#quick-start) and based on the sample it only passes `Target` to the method's string parameter. I wonder what other option's there are?

```
private const string Target = "Target";
switch (command)
{
    case "broadcast":
        return _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync(Target, message);
    case "user":
        var userId = receiver;
        return _hubContext.Clients.User(userId).SendAsync(Target, message);
    case "users":
        var userIds = receiver.Split(',');
        return _hubContext.Clients.Users(userIds).SendAsync(Target, message);
    case "group":
        var groupName = receiver;
        return _hubContext.Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync(Target, message);
    case "groups":
        var groupNames = receiver.Split(',');
        return _hubContext.Clients.Groups(groupNames).SendAsync(Target, message);
    default:
        Console.WriteLine($"Can't recognize command {command}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: The value of `Target` specifies the client method to be called. So there is supposed to be a "Target" method in the client app in this particular example. You may of course rename the method to whatever you want provided that you change the value of the `Target` on the server-side.

Comment: @mm8 Yes, but the Target method is called is implemented in the SDK. So I wonder if there are other methods other than "Target" method.

Comment: Check the source code to see whether `SendAsync` is called with any other value then? Apparently `Target` is a constant in the code snippet you have posted.